# Bivariate legend plugin throws NameError exception

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, legend

While using QGIS 3.10 and 3.16 on Mac OS X Big Sur, the Bivariate legend plugin throws a `NameError` exception. How do I fix this or work around it?

The following stack trace is from QGIS 3.10. The 3.16 stack trace seems similar.

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

```py
NameError: name 'Qgis' is not defined 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/judithheher/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/BivariateLegend/bivariate_legend.py", line 400, in generate_image
    level=Qgis.Info
NameError: name 'Qgis' is not defined
```

**Versions:**
Python version: 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:23:15) [Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)]
QGIS version: 3.10.11-A Coruña A Coruña, d2171173e4

**Python Path:**

```bsh
/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python
/Users/judithheher/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/judithheher/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/python
/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7
/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python37.zip
/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geos
/Users/judithheher/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/judithheher/Documents/Home/SJSU/GEOG171/Week4
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The file `bivariate_legend.py` has a missing import.

- Open file `/Users/judithheher/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/BivariateLegend/bivariate_legend.py` in any editor.
- Add `from qgis.core import Qgis` to the import section.
- Restart QGIS and retry. The plugin will run seamlessly.

Comment: Made the fix in the original plugin (I'm the maintainer). Waiting for plugin approval. Thanks for the feedback on the tracker @Kadir Şahbaz

Comment: This worked like a charm! BTW I tried to find a way to contact you, ThomasG77, but couldn't the QGIS site kept me going in circles.

Comment: If any other issues with my plugin or someone else, go to https://plugins.qgis.org, search the plugin, click on it and then, in the tabs, click on "Details" and find the "Code repository" to be redirected to the code repository. In my case, http://github.com/webgeodatavore/bivariate_legend/. Then, you can go to "issues" tab and create a "New issue". You need a Github account to to this but for some other repositories, it could be bitbucket, gitlab or dedicated hosting for git repository